# Backintime backup utility on Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: backintime

I have an encrypted home directory; the directory i want to backup is on a windows partition and the target is an ext3 partition.
The backup should be encrypted and the password saved in kwallet.

I would like to run "backintime" on logout or shutdown, so even if booting to the windows directory and doing some mess I can still restore the files from linux-partition (Kubuntu-16.04).
How can I achieve this?

Comment: not sure about the backintime part but, you can use borgbackup to do the backup and encryption. https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: thanks,  the encryption part of backintime seems ok . So now I have to set the automation part , backing up at logout or shutdown.